# Removing lower pixel valued connected components from image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, machine-learning, opencv3.0

Is there any way to remove the lower pixel valued connected components from the below picture? Like I want the ***horizontal and vertical lines and small already printed texts*** removed except the handwritten text.

[image: Picture with handwritten text with noise]

I want the handwritten text to be extracted like in this image.

[image]

Is there any specific library I can use for this purpose?
I was trying Python OpenCV's library to threshold the noise pixels out of the image but that is not giving perfect result.
The image I'm getting after using threshold is this.

[image]

If I increase the threshold then it is removing pixels from the handwritten text itself.

Comment: Perhaps if you show what you have tried someone might be able to suggest an improvement.

Comment: okay added the reference image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the OpenCV methods erode and dilate. They are able to first (erode) get rid of noise and then amplify the main signale (dilate).

Comment: Thanks, this worked a little. Now noise is not totally removed yet, but yes comparatively less.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop an algorithm based "connected component analysis" to remove undesired connected components. You just need to detect connected components and remove the small ones to extract the desired ones. A case study about it can be found in [**here**](https://github.com/ahmetozlu/signature_extractor) and can be helpful for you to develop the solution for your case.